# Spark Streaming Context Hangs on Start

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

All,

I am trying to use Kinesis with Spark Streaming on Spark 1.6.0 via Databricks and my `ssc.start()` command is hanging.

I am using the following function to make my Spark Streaming Context:

```
def creatingFunc(sc: SparkContext): StreamingContext = 
{
        // Create a StreamingContext
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds))

        // Creata a Kinesis stream
        val kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc,
            kinesisAppName, kinesisStreamName,
            kinesisEndpointUrl, RegionUtils.getRegionByEndpoint(kinesisEndpointUrl).getName,
            InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, Seconds(kinesisCheckpointIntervalSeconds),
            StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2, config.awsAccessKeyId, config.awsSecretKey)

        kinesisStream.print()

        ssc.remember(Minutes(1))
        ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
        ssc
}
```

However when I run the following to start the streaming context:

```
// Stop any existing StreamingContext 
val stopActiveContext = true
if (stopActiveContext) {    
  StreamingContext.getActive.foreach { _.stop(stopSparkContext = false) }
} 

// Get or create a streaming context.
val ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(() => main.creatingFunc(sc))

// This starts the streaming context in the background. 
ssc.start()
```

The last bit, `ssc.start()`, hangs indefinitely without issuing any log messages. I am running this on a freshly spun up cluster with no other notebooks attached so there aren't any other streaming contexts running.

Any thoughts?

Additionally, here are the libraries I am using (from my build.sbt file):

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0"
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0"
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10" % "1.6.0"
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.0"
```

**Edit 1:**
After running the code again recently, I got the following error:

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out retrying send to http://10.210.224.74:7070: 2 hours; nested exception is: 
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out retrying send to http://10.210.224.74:7070: 2 hours
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DbfsClient.send0(DbfsClient.scala:71)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DbfsClient.sendIdempotent(DbfsClient.scala:40)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.listStatus(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.FileBasedWriteAheadLog.initializeOrRecover(FileBasedWriteAheadLog.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.FileBasedWriteAheadLog.<init>(FileBasedWriteAheadLog.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:141)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$.createLog(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$.createLogForDriver(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker$$anonfun$createWriteAheadLog$1.apply(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker$$anonfun$createWriteAheadLog$1.apply(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:252)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.createWriteAheadLog(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.<init>(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.<init>(ReceiverTracker.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.start(JobScheduler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamingContext.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:606)
    at ... run in separate thread using org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils ... ()
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:600)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out retrying send to http://10.210.224.74:7070: 2 hours
    at com.databricks.rpc.ReliableJettyClient.retryOnNetworkError(ReliableJettyClient.scala:138)
    at com.databricks.rpc.ReliableJettyClient.sendIdempotent(ReliableJettyClient.scala:46)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DbfsClient.doSend(DbfsClient.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DbfsClient.send0(DbfsClient.scala:60)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DbfsClient.sendIdempotent(DbfsClient.scala:40)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.listStatus(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.FileBasedWriteAheadLog.initializeOrRecover(FileBasedWriteAheadLog.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.FileBasedWriteAheadLog.<init>(FileBasedWriteAheadLog.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:141)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$.createLog(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils$.createLogForDriver(WriteAheadLogUtils.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker$$anonfun$createWriteAheadLog$1.apply(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker$$anonfun$createWriteAheadLog$1.apply(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:252)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.createWriteAheadLog(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.<init>(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.<init>(ReceiverTracker.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.start(JobScheduler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamingContext.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.run(ThreadUtils.scala:122)
```

Comment: I guess you will need to start discarding problem elements: replace the kinesis dstream by a `constantOutputDStream`  and try again. I've not used the databricks notebook with streaming. Where is that `print() ` expected to output something?

Comment: On Databricks it would just go to the Standard Output, I only added it because it represents a minimal action (which is required for the stream to start).

I will try using a DStream instead and report on the result

Comment: Huh, I tried the Databricks standard example using a standard DStream and a dummy data source that they put together and that doesn't work either. Same thing, the start command hangs.

Comment: After removing all unnecessary libraries, I was able to get the Databricks standard streaming example with dummy data to work. The Kinesis stream is still not working